# How to confirm that the message has been sent to the RabbitMQ queue?

Tags: node.js, rabbitmq

I send messages to the RabbitMQ queue but a consumer receives nothing.

```
channel.assertQueue(config.amqp.queue
```

Shows

```
{ queue: 'tasks', messageCount: 0, consumerCount: 1 }
```

The consumer show nothing. Admin panel show nothing.
How to confirm that the message has been sent to the RabbitMQ queue?
I am sendin the way
const ok = await channel.assertQueue(config.amqp.queue, {
    durable: true
  });

I am sending by:

```
  await channel.sendToQueue(config.asteriskAmi.queue, Buffer.from('string'));
```

Answer (score 1):

**PLEASE**

Do not hesitate on providing any *environment detail* that may help answering your question on SO: e.g. the packages you're using, how you initialised the variables you're using, etc.

---

**TO ANSWER**

In the [amqplib documentation](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html) (I guess this is the package you're using), there is a [specific type of *channel*](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#confirmchannel) that uses **acknowledgement** to indicate a message has been successfully received by the RabbitMQ server:

```js
import * as amqp from "amqplib";

// Initialise `AMQP_OPTIONS` and `message` here, e.g.:
/* const AMQP_OPTIONS = {
    frameMax: 0,
    heartbeat: 0,
    hostname: "localhost",
    locale: "en_GB",
    password: "guest",
    port: 5672,
    protocol: "amqp",
    username: "guest",
    vhost: "/",
};

const message = "Hello, world!"; */

const connection = await amqp.connect(AMQP_OPTIONS);
const confirmChannel = await connection.createConfirmChannel();
await confirmChannel.assertQueue(config.amqp.queue);
confirmChannel.sendToQueue(
  config.amqp.queue, // Perhaps you wanted 'config.asteriskAmi.queue' here ?
  Buffer.from(message),
  {},
  (err, ok) => {
    if (err !== null) {
      console.error(err);
      // Error handling
    }
    else {
      console.info("Message successfully acked!");
      // Success handling
    }
  }
);
```

**NB**: Your problem may also be your consumer subscribing to `config.amqp.queue` while you publish to `config.asteriskAmi.queue`.

Hope it helps. In case you need more details about `confirmChannel.sendToQueue`, here is the [documentation](https://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#confirmchannel_sendToQueue).

Answer (score 0):

Using standard AMQP 0-9-1, the only way to guarantee that a message isn't lost is by using transactions -- make the channel transactional then for each message or set of messages publish, commit. In this case, transactions are unnecessarily heavyweight and decrease throughput by a factor of 250. To remedy this, a confirmation mechanism was introduced. It mimics the consumer acknowledgements mechanism already present in the protocol.

To enable confirms, a client sends the confirm.select method. Depending on whether no-wait was set or not, the broker may respond with a `confirm.select-ok`. Once the confirm.select method is used on a channel, it is said to be in confirm mode. A transactional channel cannot be put into confirm mode and once a channel is in confirm mode, it cannot be made transactional.

Once a channel is in confirm mode, both the broker and the client count messages (counting starts at 1 on the first confirm.select). The broker then confirms messages as it handles them by sending a `basic.ack` on the same channel. The `delivery-tag` field contains the sequence number of the confirmed message. The broker may also set the multiple field in `basic.ack` to indicate that all messages up to and including the one with the sequence number have been handled.

Further reading can be done here https://www.rabbitmq.com/confirms.html

Comment: A very well explained sample can be found here http://www.squaremobius.net/amqp.node/channel_api.html#confirmchannel